# Woocommerce Variation dropdown not showing options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a problem with this [website](http://www.tante-anna.dk/produkt/neosens_sko/), it is not showing the options on the variation dropdown. Here is my setup. [image: here is the image]. The website is using a custom theme.

Comment: Did you add a price for each variation?

Comment: Honestly no, I did not add prices on each variations.